# Stopping js ajax call from a specific user

Tags: ajax, wordpress, apache

I have done something silly and written a script for a website that does an ajax check every 2 seconds. In this case its using wordpress and its admin-ajax.php file every 2 seconds. This essentially burned up all the CPU power of the server, and made every site on the server run really slowly.

After a lot of detective work, i finally found the script and stopped it, so that it doesn't happen on new loads of that website. But looking at my apache log, i can see that it is still running in one browser somewhere.

Is there a way for me to stop that browser from requesting that ajax-call, or perhaps block it from my server? Or will I just have to wait until that browser is being refreshed or closed?

Comment: You could block the IP Adress. Bit if tue IP is dynamically assigned you will have the Problem again.

Is it you who requests the Page?

Comment: I actually just added this line: 'deny from {ip address}' to my .htaccess file - and now they're getting a 403 denied - thank you

Comment: you can also restrict user-agent for that browser (if it has smth strange in it). Here's sample of code you'll need to add in your .htaccess file:  
  
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    #block unwanted user agents  
    BrowserMatchNoCase "DotBot" blocked  
    BrowserMatchNoCase "-" blocked  
    Order allow,deny  
    Deny from env=blocked  
    #restrict access for a single ip address  
    Deny from 5.39.218.37  
    #restrict access for a range of ip addresses  
    Deny from 66.155.10.  
    Allow from all  
</IfModule>`

Comment: sorry for the missing line breaks in comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [netstat](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/netstat-command-examples/) or something similar through [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) to detect the IP and port of the unknown browser. Also you should try to reboot the server so it may will loose connection.

PS: It's pretty hard to give a clue or answer in the right direction without having any logs or evidence to ensure you answer to this question correctly.